# Phonegap deploy iphone app without iphone and ios developer account

Tags: iphone, cordova, deployment

I have created my first IPhone app using mac and phonegap. The app runs fine on mac IPhone emulator. I don't own an Iphone.  Now I want to give this app to my friend to test on iPhone. I don't want to sell this app on app store so don't want to spend $99 per year on developer certificate. Can any one please tell me how can I give the app to friend to test and run. I know when I create android app with phonegap it generates the .apk file which has a debug certificate in it to test on phone and I can copy that .apk file into android phone and run the app. Is phonegap for iphone also generate such a executable like .apk file in android which I can give to my friend. Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to generate an `ipa` for your app, to install the app on a device for testing, distribution, or even upload to the App Store, you must have required `provisioning profiles`, which must be signed with a matching development certificate.

Unfortunately, you must have a developer account to be able to generate said provisioning profiles. From Apple's site:

> When you’re ready to share your app for user testing or for general distribution through the App Store, you need to create an archive of the app using a **distribution provisioning profile** and send it to app testers or submit it to iTunes Connect.

This is taken from this link:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/35-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH10-SW2

Comment: What about iphone. Do I need it too or I can create the app without it and send the ipa to my friend

Comment: No, you don't need to have an iPhone to create the `ipa`. (However, should you later decide you *do* want to upload to the App Store, it is highly recommended by Apple that you first test on an actual device, which can behave pretty differently than the simulator for some things.)

Comment: Than where I can find the generated ipa file in my project?